# Java script written for UUID is not working in jmeter

Tags: javascript, jmeter, jsr223

Find below the code we have developed in java script to run in jmeter using JSR223 sampler(running as a java script). The same code worked on Jquery when developed but not posting the id while running in jmeter. the error thrown is "appid" is not defined. Could someone help debugging the issue looking at the code

```
vars.put("guid", "${__UUID}"); 
vars.put("appId", "ce547c40-acf9-11e6-80f5-76304dec7eb7");
var id=getAppInfo(appId, guid);
```

function getAppInfo(appId, guid) 
    {

```
    var appInfo = null;
    var appIdBytes = guidToBytes(appId);
    var guidBytes = guidToBytes(guid);
    var appInfoBytes = [];
    for (var cnt = 0; cnt < appIdBytes.length; cnt++) 
    {
        appInfoBytes[cnt] = appIdBytes[cnt] + guidBytes[cnt];
    }
    var appInfoGuidfromBytes = bytesToGuid(appInfoBytes);
    return appInfoGuidfromBytes;
}  

function bytesToGuid(guidBytes) {
    var x = guidBytes;
    var result = "";
    var bytes = x.slice(0, 4).reverse().concat(x.slice(4, 6).reverse()).concat(x.slice(6, 8).reverse()).concat(x.slice(8));

    var y = bytes.map(function (item) { return ('00' + item.toString(16)).substr(-2, 2) });
    var byteArray = y;
    for (var cnt = 0; cnt < byteArray.length; cnt++) {
        if (cnt === 4 || cnt === 6 || cnt === 8 || cnt === 10)
            result = result + "-" + byteArray[cnt];
        else
            result = result + byteArray[cnt];
    }
    return result;
}
function guidToBytes(guid) {
    var bytes = [];
    guid.split('-').map(function (number, index) {
        var bytesInChar = index < 3 ? number.match(/.{1,2}/g).reverse() : number.match(/.{1,2}/g);
        bytesInChar.map(function (byte) { bytes.push(parseInt(byte, 16)); });
    });
    return bytes;
}

// Create the Randon Number. It will call from NewGuid function.
function getRandomNumber() {
    return (((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000) | 0).toString(16).substring(1);    
};
// Creating GUID eg. "cbe26df8-2b01-4377-9ae8-1d023ccd5171"
// getRandomNumber returns 4 digit Alphanumeric number and we are going to concatenating this with "-" symbol and third number starts with "-4" and substring the random number and concatenate the string and return.

function newGuid() {
    return (getRandomNumber() + getRandomNumber() + "-" + getRandomNumber() + "-4" + getRandomNumber().substr(0, 3) + "-" + getRandomNumber() + "-" + getRandomNumber() + getRandomNumber() + getRandomNumber()).toLowerCase();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't call JMeter's function inside [JSR223 script](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223).

Instead, add it to Parameters field as `${__UUID}`

and then use it using [args](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler):

```
vars.put("guid", args[0]);
```

> args - the parameters as a String array (split on whitespace)